# How to use humanoid_walk

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Hello Everyone!!**

**How to use Humanoid_walk**

**Install:**
Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise)

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list':

wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop-full

echo "source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc

. ~/.bashrc

source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash
```

**Others:**

```
sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall python-rosdep

sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-qt-gui-core ros-fuerte-rqt

sudo apt-get install git
```

**Run In A Terminal:**

```
roscore
```

**Another Terminal:**

```
source ~/'ros'/setup.sh

roscd

git clone https://github.com/laas/humanoid_walk.git;

rosws set humanoid_walk

roscd humanoid_walk

roscd walk_interfacesmake

rosws set walk_interfaces

roscd walk_interfaces

make  

rosws set walk_msgs

roscd walk_msgs

make 

rosws set walk_tools

roscd walk_tools

make 

rosws set halfsteps_pattern_generator

roscd halfsteps_pattern_generator

make 

rosrun halfsteps_pattern_generator generator
```

**Another Terminal:**

```
source ~/'ros'/setup.sh

roscd halfsteps_pattern_generator

./samples/tutorial_getting_started.py
```

**Another Terminal:**

```
rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find walk_msgs`/walking_trajectories.vcg
```

http://www.ros.org/wiki/halfsteps_pattern_generator

Kindest regards,

Vincent

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62860/how-to-use-humanoid_walk/) by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2013-05-15

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-05-26**:
Maintainer here. Can you edit the post and translate the spanish part? I will then try to answer your question here. Thanks.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2013-05-30**:
I translated it for you. Still don't know what you're asking, Vincent.... Is this a tutorial? ¿Es esto un tutorial?

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2013-06-03**:
This is a tutorial, but I have problem with this:

http://answers.ros.org/question/63525/how-use-rosrun-walk_msgs-generator-_yamlsampleshort_walkyaml/

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2013-06-03**:
@Thomas, is this tutorial correct?

how could edit the trayectory of foot?

to senosoidal?

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-06-06**:
I am sorry but what is your issue? Can you please merge the quesiton and tell me: 1. what you want to achieve? 2. what result you obtain? Thanks!

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2013-06-09**:
2. I have an error when use:

rosrun walk_msgs generator _yaml:=/sample/short_walk.yaml

fatal error: bad type for pattern generator node (expected type: map, parsed type: null) [ERROR] [1369543267.813844427]: fatal error: bad type for pattern generator node (expected type: map, parsed type: null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to change the yaml argument to the *real* path of your yaml file. Examples files can be downloaded from the wiki.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0